# Drag div from sidebar to table with jquery ui

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm beginer to js and jquery and I need a little help if someone can help me...

What I want to do?

I want to drag div from sidebar to table. In sidebar div must be only draggable to table. When I drag div to table, there in table, div must be resizable and draggable again.

Photo:
[image]

I was try with this code but dont work well:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).resizable();
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({revert: 'invalid', helper:'clone', snap: "#drop_here td", opacity: 0.7});
    $( "#drop_here td" ).droppable({
      accept: '.draggable',
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
      }
    });
  });
```

DEMO and SOURCE code: http://jsbin.com/erofot/17/edit | http://jsbin.com/erofot/17

Comment: Am i missing something ? Isn't that exactly what your code is doing already ? Or did i mis something ?

Comment: yes but I can't clone element, I drag original element :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you could do it then: (replace what you have in jsbin with this code)
[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/erofot/105/edit)

```
$(function() {
    //$( ".draggable" ).resizable();
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
      revert: 'invalid', 
      helper:"clone",
      snap: "#drop_here td", 
      opacity: 0.7
    });
    $( "#drop_here td" ).droppable({
      // accept only from left div, 
      // this is necessary  to prevent clones duplicating inside droppable
      accept: '#left .draggable',
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        // 4 append clone to droppable
        $( this ).append(
          // 1 clone draggable helper
          $(ui.helper).clone()
          // 2 make the clone draggable
          .draggable({containment:"parent"})
          // 3 make the clone resizable
          .resizable());
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: I don't know why but when I copy this code to my original code(when implement this to my app) the div .draggable won't to append on position I drag him, Div append on my position + 50,70,100px right etc. or something like that

Comment: and also please show me how the clonable div can be draggable only into table?

Comment: yes, THANKS THANKS very much, I'll see why in my original code when I drag div to table he get position (original position + 100px right). He dont want to stay where I put him. But thanks very mch for this code